# PyQT5 5.15.0 source build using Visual Studio 2015 for Python 2.7 with QT 5.15.0 and is Failing with error

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I am trying to build the PyQt5 5.15.0 Source code using Visual Studio 2015 for Python 2.7.
Have installed QT 5.15.0 full version, But the building of code is failing. Here are the steps i did

1. Dowmload SIP and PyQt5 latest from the RiverBank Website.
2. Built the SIP, and the SIP build was successful.

   - python configure.py --platform=win32-msvc2015
   - nmake
   - nmake install
3. Building the PyQt5

   - python configure.py
   - nmake

with nmake i get the Failing with following error:

```
C:\Qt5.15.0\PyQt5-5.15.1.dev2006161728.tar\PyQt5-5.15.1.dev2006161728\PyQt5-5.15.1.dev2006161728>nmake

Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 14.00.24210.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

        cd QtCore\ && ( if not exist Makefile C:\Qt\Qt5.15.0\5.15.0\msvc2015_64\bin\qmake.exe -o Makefile C:\Qt5.15.0\PyQt5-5.15.1.dev2006161728.tar\PyQt5-5.15.1.dev2006161728\PyQt5-5.15.1.dev2006161728\QtCore\QtCore.pro ) && "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\amd64\nmake.exe" -f Makefile

Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 14.00.24210.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

        "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\amd64\nmake.exe" -f Makefile.Release

Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 14.00.24210.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

        cd QtGui\ && ( if not exist Makefile C:\Qt\Qt5.15.0\5.15.0\msvc2015_64\bin\qmake.exe -o Makefile C:\Qt5.15.0\PyQt5-5.15.1.dev2006161728.tar\PyQt5-5.15.1.dev2006161728\PyQt5-5.15.1.dev2006161728\QtGui\QtGui.pro ) && "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\amd64\nmake.exe" -f Makefile

Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 14.00.24210.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

        "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\amd64\nmake.exe" -f Makefile.Release

Microsoft (R) Program Maintenance Utility Version 14.00.24210.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

        cl -c -nologo -Zc:wchar_t -FS -Zc:rvalueCast -Zc:inline -Zc:strictStrings -Zc:throwingNew -O2 -MD /wd4530 /wd4577 -W3 -w34100 -w34189 -w44996 -w44456 -w44457 -w44458 -wd4577 -wd4467 -DUNICODE -D_UNICODE -DWIN32 -D_ENABLE_EXTENDED_ALIGNED_STORAGE -DWIN64 -DPy_LIMITED_API=0x03040000 -DNDEBUG -DQT_NO_EXCEPTIONS -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_PLUGIN -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -D_WINDLL -I. -I. -IC:\Python27\include -I..\qpy\QtGui -IC:\Qt\Qt5.15.0\5.15.0\msvc2015_64\include -IC:\Qt\Qt5.15.0\5.15.0\msvc2015_64\include\QtGui -IC:\Qt\Qt5.15.0\5.15.0\msvc2015_64\include\QtANGLE -IC:\Qt\Qt5.15.0\5.15.0\msvc2015_64\include\QtCore -Irelease -I/include -IC:\Qt\Qt5.15.0\5.15.0\msvc2015_64\mkspecs\win32-msvc -Forelease\ @C:\Users\BLRACO~1\AppData\Local\Temp\nm132C.tmp
sipQtGuiQColorConstants.cpp
c:\users\nxa35232\appdata\local\programs\common\microsoft\visual c++ for python\9.0\winsdk\include\sal_supp.h(57): warning C4005: '__useHeader': macro redefinition
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\sal.h(2866): note: see previous definition of '__useHeader'
c:\users\nxa35232\appdata\local\programs\common\microsoft\visual c++ for python\9.0\winsdk\include\specstrings_supp.h(77): warning C4005: '__on_failure': macro redefinition
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\sal.h(2876): note: see previous definition of '__on_failure'
.\sipQtGuiQColorConstants.cpp(40): error C2039: 'Black': is not a member of 'QColorConstants'
C:\Qt\Qt5.15.0\5.15.0\msvc2015_64\include\QtGui\qcolor.h(336): note: see declaration of 'QColorConstants'
.\sipQtGuiQColorConstants.cpp(40): error C2065: 'Black': undeclared identifier
.\sipQtGuiQColorConstants.cpp(51): error C2039: 'Blue': is not a member of 'QColorConstants'
C:\Qt\Qt5.15.0\5.15.0\msvc2015_64\include\QtGui\qcolor.h(336): note: see declaration of 'QColorConstants'
.\sipQtGuiQColorConstants.cpp(51): error C2065: 'Blue': undeclared identifier
.\sipQtGuiQColorConstants.cpp(62): error C2039: 'Color0': is not a member of 'QColorConstants'
C:\Qt\Qt5.15.0\5.15.0\msvc2015_64\include\QtGui\qcolor.h(336): note: see declaration of 'QColorConstants'
.\sipQtGuiQColorConstants.cpp(62): error C2065: 'Color0': undeclared identifier
.\sipQtGuiQColorConstants.cpp(73): error C2039: 'Color1': is not a member of 'QColorConstants'
C:\Qt\Qt5.15.0\5.15.0\msvc2015_64\include\QtGui\qcolor.h(336): note: see declaration of 'QColorConstants'
.\sipQtGuiQColorConstants.cpp(73): error C2065: 'Color1': undeclared identifier
.\sipQtGuiQColorConstants.cpp(84): error C2039: 'Cyan': is not a member of 'QColorConstants'
C:\Qt\Qt5.15.0\5.15.0\msvc2015_64\include\QtGui\qcolor.h(336): note: see declaration of 'QColorConstants'
.\sipQtGuiQColorConstants.cpp(84): error C2065: 'Cyan': undeclared identifier
.\sipQtGuiQColorConstants.cpp(95): error C2039: 'DarkBlue': is not a member of 'QColorConstants'
C:\Qt\Qt5.15.0\5.15.0\msvc2015_64\include\QtGui\qcolor.h(336): note: see declaration of 'QColorConstants'
.\sipQtGuiQColorConstants.cpp(95): error C2065: 'DarkBlue': undeclared identifier
.\sipQtGuiQColorConstants.cpp(106): error C2039: 'DarkCyan': is not a member of 'QColorConstants'
C:\Qt\Qt5.15.0\5.15.0\msvc2015_64\include\QtGui\qcolor.h(336): note: see declaration of 'QColorConstants'
.\sipQtGuiQColorConstants.cpp(106): error C2065: 'DarkCyan': undeclared identifier
.\sipQtGuiQColorConstants.cpp(117): error C2039: 'DarkGray': is not a member of 'QColorConstants'
C:\Qt\Qt5.15.0\5.15.0\msvc2015_64\include\QtGui\qcolor.h(336): note: see declaration of 'QColorConstants'
.\sipQtGuiQColorConstants.cpp(117): error C2065: 'DarkGray': undeclared identifier
.\sipQtGuiQColorConstants.cpp(128): error C2039: 'DarkGreen': is not a member of 'QColorConstants'
C:\Qt\Qt5.15.0\5.15.0\msvc2015_64\include\QtGui\qcolor.h(336): note: see declaration of 'QColorConstants'
.\sipQtGuiQColorConstants.cpp(128): error C2065: 'DarkGreen': undeclared identifier
.\sipQtGuiQColorConstants.cpp(139): error C2039: 'DarkMagenta': is not a member of 'QColorConstants'
C:\Qt\Qt5.15.0\5.15.0\msvc2015_64\include\QtGui\qcolor.h(336): note: see declaration of 'QColorConstants'
.\sipQtGuiQColorConstants.cpp(139): error C2065: 'DarkMagenta': undeclared identifier
.\sipQtGuiQColorConstants.cpp(150): error C2039: 'DarkRed': is not a member of 'QColorConstants'
C:\Qt\Qt5.15.0\5.15.0\msvc2015_64\include\QtGui\qcolor.h(336): note: see declaration of 'QColorConstants'
.\sipQtGuiQColorConstants.cpp(150): error C2065: 'DarkRed': undeclared identifier
.\sipQtGuiQColorConstants.cpp(161): error C2039: 'DarkYellow': is not a member of 'QColorConstants'
C:\Qt\Qt5.15.0\5.15.0\msvc2015_64\include\QtGui\qcolor.h(336): note: see declaration of 'QColorConstants'
.\sipQtGuiQColorConstants.cpp(161): error C2065: 'DarkYellow': undeclared identifier
.\sipQtGuiQColorConstants.cpp(172): error C2039: 'Gray': is not a member of 'QColorConstants'
C:\Qt\Qt5.15.0\5.15.0\msvc2015_64\include\QtGui\qcolor.h(336): note: see declaration of 'QColorConstants'
.\sipQtGuiQColorConstants.cpp(172): error C2065: 'Gray': undeclared identifier
.\sipQtGuiQColorConstants.cpp(183): error C2039: 'Green': is not a member of 'QColorConstants'
C:\Qt\Qt5.15.0\5.15.0\msvc2015_64\include\QtGui\qcolor.h(336): note: see declaration of 'QColorConstants'
.\sipQtGuiQColorConstants.cpp(183): error C2065: 'Green': undeclared identifier
.\sipQtGuiQColorConstants.cpp(194): error C2039: 'LightGray': is not a member of 'QColorConstants'
C:\Qt\Qt5.15.0\5.15.0\msvc2015_64\include\QtGui\qcolor.h(336): note: see declaration of 'QColorConstants'
.\sipQtGuiQColorConstants.cpp(194): error C2065: 'LightGray': undeclared identifier
.\sipQtGuiQColorConstants.cpp(205): error C2039: 'Magenta': is not a member of 'QColorConstants'
C:\Qt\Qt5.15.0\5.15.0\msvc2015_64\include\QtGui\qcolor.h(336): note: see declaration of 'QColorConstants'
.\sipQtGuiQColorConstants.cpp(205): error C2065: 'Magenta': undeclared identifier
.\sipQtGuiQColorConstants.cpp(216): error C2039: 'Red': is not a member of 'QColorConstants'
C:\Qt\Qt5.15.0\5.15.0\msvc2015_64\include\QtGui\qcolor.h(336): note: see declaration of 'QColorConstants'
.\sipQtGuiQColorConstants.cpp(216): error C2065: 'Red': undeclared identifier
.\sipQtGuiQColorConstants.cpp(227): error C2039: 'Transparent': is not a member of 'QColorConstants'
C:\Qt\Qt5.15.0\5.15.0\msvc2015_64\include\QtGui\qcolor.h(336): note: see declaration of 'QColorConstants'
.\sipQtGuiQColorConstants.cpp(227): error C2065: 'Transparent': undeclared identifier
.\sipQtGuiQColorConstants.cpp(238): error C2039: 'White': is not a member of 'QColorConstants'
C:\Qt\Qt5.15.0\5.15.0\msvc2015_64\include\QtGui\qcolor.h(336): note: see declaration of 'QColorConstants'
.\sipQtGuiQColorConstants.cpp(238): error C2065: 'White': undeclared identifier
.\sipQtGuiQColorConstants.cpp(249): error C2039: 'Yellow': is not a member of 'QColorConstants'
C:\Qt\Qt5.15.0\5.15.0\msvc2015_64\include\QtGui\qcolor.h(336): note: see declaration of 'QColorConstants'
.\sipQtGuiQColorConstants.cpp(249): error C2065: 'Yellow': undeclared identifier
sipQtGuiQColorConstantsSvg.cpp
c:\users\nxa35232\appdata\local\programs\common\microsoft\visual c++ for python\9.0\winsdk\include\sal_supp.h(57): warning C4005: '__useHeader': macro redefinition
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\sal.h(2866): note: see previous definition of '__useHeader'
c:\users\nxa35232\appdata\local\programs\common\microsoft\visual c++ for python\9.0\winsdk\include\specstrings_supp.h(77): warning C4005: '__on_failure': macro redefinition
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\include\sal.h(2876): note: see previous definition of '__on_failure'
.\sipQtGuiQColorConstantsSvg.cpp(42): error C2039: 'aliceblue': is not a member of 'QColorConstants::Svg'
C:\Qt\Qt5.15.0\5.15.0\msvc2015_64\include\QtGui\qcolor.h(338): note: see declaration of 'QColorConstants::Svg'
.\sipQtGuiQColorConstantsSvg.cpp(42): error C2065: 'aliceblue': undeclared identifier
.\sipQtGuiQColorConstantsSvg.cpp(53): error C2039: 'antiquewhite': is not a member of 'QColorConstants::Svg'
C:\Qt\Qt5.15.0\5.15.0\msvc2015_64\include\QtGui\qcolor.h(338): note: see declaration of 'QColorConstants::Svg'
.\sipQtGuiQColorConstantsSvg.cpp(53): error C2065: 'antiquewhite': undeclared identifier
.\sipQtGuiQColorConstantsSvg.cpp(64): error C2039: 'aqua': is not a member of 'QColorConstants::Svg'
C:\Qt\Qt5.15.0\5.15.0\msvc2015_64\include\QtGui\qcolor.h(338): note: see declaration of 'QColorConstants::Svg'
.\sipQtGuiQColorConstantsSvg.cpp(64): error C2065: 'aqua': undeclared identifier
.\sipQtGuiQColorConstantsSvg.cpp(75): error C2039: 'aquamarine': is not a member of 'QColorConstants::Svg'
C:\Qt\Qt5.15.0\5.15.0\msvc2015_64\include\QtGui\qcolor.h(338): note: see declaration of 'QColorConstants::Svg'
.\sipQtGuiQColorConstantsSvg.cpp(75): error C2065: 'aquamarine': undeclared identifier
.\sipQtGuiQColorConstantsSvg.cpp(86): error C2039: 'azure': is not a member of 'QColorConstants::Svg'
C:\Qt\Qt5.15.0\5.15.0\msvc2015_64\include\QtGui\qcolor.h(338): note: see declaration of 'QColorConstants::Svg'
.\sipQtGuiQColorConstantsSvg.cpp(86): error C2065: 'azure': undeclared identifier
.\sipQtGuiQColorConstantsSvg.cpp(97): error C2039: 'beige': is not a member of 'QColorConstants::Svg'
C:\Qt\Qt5.15.0\5.15.0\msvc2015_64\include\QtGui\qcolor.h(338): note: see declaration of 'QColorConstants::Svg'
.\sipQtGuiQColorConstantsSvg.cpp(97): error C2065: 'beige': undeclared identifier
.\sipQtGuiQColorConstantsSvg.cpp(108): error C2039: 'bisque': is not a member of 'QColorConstants::Svg'
C:\Qt\Qt5.15.0\5.15.0\msvc2015_64\include\QtGui\qcolor.h(338): note: see declaration of 'QColorConstants::Svg'
.\sipQtGuiQColorConstantsSvg.cpp(108): error C2065: 'bisque': undeclared identifier
.\sipQtGuiQColorConstantsSvg.cpp(119): error C2039: 'black': is not a member of 'QColorConstants::Svg'
C:\Qt\Qt5.15.0\5.15.0\msvc2015_64\include\QtGui\qcolor.h(338): note: see declaration of 'QColorConstants::Svg'
.\sipQtGuiQColorConstantsSvg.cpp(119): error C2065: 'black': undeclared identifier
.\sipQtGuiQColorConstantsSvg.cpp(130): error C2039: 'blanchedalmond': is not a member of 'QColorConstants::Svg'
C:\Qt\Qt5.15.0\5.15.0\msvc2015_64\include\QtGui\qcolor.h(338): note: see declaration of 'QColorConstants::Svg'
.\sipQtGuiQColorConstantsSvg.cpp(130): error C2065: 'blanchedalmond': undeclared identifier
.\sipQtGuiQColorConstantsSvg.cpp(141): error C2039: 'blue': is not a member of 'QColorConstants::Svg'
C:\Qt\Qt5.15.0\5.15.0\msvc2015_64\include\QtGui\qcolor.h(338): note: see declaration of 'QColorConstants::Svg'
.\sipQtGuiQColorConstantsSvg.cpp(141): error C2065: 'blue': undeclared identifier
.\sipQtGuiQColorConstantsSvg.cpp(152): error C2039: 'blueviolet': is not a member of 'QColorConstants::Svg'
C:\Qt\Qt5.15.0\5.15.0\msvc2015_64\include\QtGui\qcolor.h(338): note: see declaration of 'QColorConstants::Svg'
.\sipQtGuiQColorConstantsSvg.cpp(152): error C2065: 'blueviolet': undeclared identifier
.\sipQtGuiQColorConstantsSvg.cpp(163): error C2039: 'brown': is not a member of 'QColorConstants::Svg'
C:\Qt\Qt5.15.0\5.15.0\msvc2015_64\include\QtGui\qcolor.h(338): note: see declaration of 'QColorConstants::Svg'
.\sipQtGuiQColorConstantsSvg.cpp(163): error C2065: 'brown': undeclared identifier
.\sipQtGuiQColorConstantsSvg.cpp(174): error C2039: 'burlywood': is not a member of 'QColorConstants::Svg'
C:\Qt\Qt5.15.0\5.15.0\msvc2015_64\include\QtGui\qcolor.h(338): note: see declaration of 'QColorConstants::Svg'
.\sipQtGuiQColorConstantsSvg.cpp(174): error C2065: 'burlywood': undeclared identifier
.\sipQtGuiQColorConstantsSvg.cpp(185): error C2039: 'cadetblue': is not a member of 'QColorConstants::Svg'
C:\Qt\Qt5.15.0\5.15.0\msvc2015_64\include\QtGui\qcolor.h(338): note: see declaration of 'QColorConstants::Svg'
.\sipQtGuiQColorConstantsSvg.cpp(185): error C2065: 'cadetblue': undeclared identifier
.\sipQtGuiQColorConstantsSvg.cpp(196): error C2039: 'chartreuse': is not a member of 'QColorConstants::Svg'
C:\Qt\Qt5.15.0\5.15.0\msvc2015_64\include\QtGui\qcolor.h(338): note: see declaration of 'QColorConstants::Svg'
.\sipQtGuiQColorConstantsSvg.cpp(196): error C2065: 'chartreuse': undeclared identifier
.\sipQtGuiQColorConstantsSvg.cpp(207): error C2039: 'chocolate': is not a member of 'QColorConstants::Svg'
C:\Qt\Qt5.15.0\5.15.0\msvc2015_64\include\QtGui\qcolor.h(338): note: see declaration of 'QColorConstants::Svg'
.\sipQtGuiQColorConstantsSvg.cpp(207): error C2065: 'chocolate': undeclared identifier
.\sipQtGuiQColorConstantsSvg.cpp(218): error C2039: 'coral': is not a member of 'QColorConstants::Svg'
C:\Qt\Qt5.15.0\5.15.0\msvc2015_64\include\QtGui\qcolor.h(338): note: see declaration of 'QColorConstants::Svg'
.\sipQtGuiQColorConstantsSvg.cpp(218): error C2065: 'coral': undeclared identifier
.\sipQtGuiQColorConstantsSvg.cpp(229): error C2039: 'cornflowerblue': is not a member of 'QColorConstants::Svg'
C:\Qt\Qt5.15.0\5.15.0\msvc2015_64\include\QtGui\qcolor.h(338): note: see declaration of 'QColorConstants::Svg'
.\sipQtGuiQColorConstantsSvg.cpp(229): error C2065: 'cornflowerblue': undeclared identifier
.\sipQtGuiQColorConstantsSvg.cpp(240): error C2039: 'cornsilk': is not a member of 'QColorConstants::Svg'
C:\Qt\Qt5.15.0\5.15.0\msvc2015_64\include\QtGui\qcolor.h(338): note: see declaration of 'QColorConstants::Svg'
.\sipQtGuiQColorConstantsSvg.cpp(240): error C2065: 'cornsilk': undeclared identifier
.\sipQtGuiQColorConstantsSvg.cpp(251): error C2039: 'crimson': is not a member of 'QColorConstants::Svg'
C:\Qt\Qt5.15.0\5.15.0\msvc2015_64\include\QtGui\qcolor.h(338): note: see declaration of 'QColorConstants::Svg'
.\sipQtGuiQColorConstantsSvg.cpp(251): error C2065: 'crimson': undeclared identifier
.\sipQtGuiQColorConstantsSvg.cpp(262): error C2039: 'cyan': is not a member of 'QColorConstants::Svg'
C:\Qt\Qt5.15.0\5.15.0\msvc2015_64\include\QtGui\qcolor.h(338): note: see declaration of 'QColorConstants::Svg'
.\sipQtGuiQColorConstantsSvg.cpp(262): error C2065: 'cyan': undeclared identifier
.\sipQtGuiQColorConstantsSvg.cpp(273): error C2039: 'darkblue': is not a member of 'QColorConstants::Svg'
C:\Qt\Qt5.15.0\5.15.0\msvc2015_64\include\QtGui\qcolor.h(338): note: see declaration of 'QColorConstants::Svg'
.\sipQtGuiQColorConstantsSvg.cpp(273): error C2065: 'darkblue': undeclared identifier
.\sipQtGuiQColorConstantsSvg.cpp(284): error C2039: 'darkcyan': is not a member of 'QColorConstants::Svg'
C:\Qt\Qt5.15.0\5.15.0\msvc2015_64\include\QtGui\qcolor.h(338): note: see declaration of 'QColorConstants::Svg'
.\sipQtGuiQColorConstantsSvg.cpp(284): error C2065: 'darkcyan': undeclared identifier
.\sipQtGuiQColorConstantsSvg.cpp(295): error C2039: 'darkgoldenrod': is not a member of 'QColorConstants::Svg'
C:\Qt\Qt5.15.0\5.15.0\msvc2015_64\include\QtGui\qcolor.h(338): note: see declaration of 'QColorConstants::Svg'
.\sipQtGuiQColorConstantsSvg.cpp(295): error C2065: 'darkgoldenrod': undeclared identifier
.\sipQtGuiQColorConstantsSvg.cpp(306): error C2039: 'darkgray': is not a member of 'QColorConstants::Svg'
C:\Qt\Qt5.15.0\5.15.0\msvc2015_64\include\QtGui\qcolor.h(338): note: see declaration of 'QColorConstants::Svg'
.\sipQtGuiQColorConstantsSvg.cpp(306): error C2065: 'darkgray': undeclared identifier
.\sipQtGuiQColorConstantsSvg.cpp(317): error C2039: 'darkgreen': is not a member of 'QColorConstants::Svg'
C:\Qt\Qt5.15.0\5.15.0\msvc2015_64\include\QtGui\qcolor.h(338): note: see declaration of 'QColorConstants::Svg'
.\sipQtGuiQColorConstantsSvg.cpp(317): error C2065: 'darkgreen': undeclared identifier
.\sipQtGuiQColorConstantsSvg.cpp(328): error C2039: 'darkgrey': is not a member of 'QColorConstants::Svg'
C:\Qt\Qt5.15.0\5.15.0\msvc2015_64\include\QtGui\qcolor.h(338): note: see declaration of 'QColorConstants::Svg'
.\sipQtGuiQColorConstantsSvg.cpp(328): error C2065: 'darkgrey': undeclared identifier
.\sipQtGuiQColorConstantsSvg.cpp(339): error C2039: 'darkkhaki': is not a member of 'QColorConstants::Svg'
C:\Qt\Qt5.15.0\5.15.0\msvc2015_64\include\QtGui\qcolor.h(338): note: see declaration of 'QColorConstants::Svg'
.\sipQtGuiQColorConstantsSvg.cpp(339): error C2065: 'darkkhaki': undeclared identifier
.\sipQtGuiQColorConstantsSvg.cpp(350): error C2039: 'darkmagenta': is not a member of 'QColorConstants::Svg'
C:\Qt\Qt5.15.0\5.15.0\msvc2015_64\include\QtGui\qcolor.h(338): note: see declaration of 'QColorConstants::Svg'
.\sipQtGuiQColorConstantsSvg.cpp(350): error C2065: 'darkmagenta': undeclared identifier
.\sipQtGuiQColorConstantsSvg.cpp(361): error C2039: 'darkolivegreen': is not a member of 'QColorConstants::Svg'
C:\Qt\Qt5.15.0\5.15.0\msvc2015_64\include\QtGui\qcolor.h(338): note: see declaration of 'QColorConstants::Svg'
.\sipQtGuiQColorConstantsSvg.cpp(361): error C2065: 'darkolivegreen': undeclared identifier
.\sipQtGuiQColorConstantsSvg.cpp(372): error C2039: 'darkorange': is not a member of 'QColorConstants::Svg'
C:\Qt\Qt5.15.0\5.15.0\msvc2015_64\include\QtGui\qcolor.h(338): note: see declaration of 'QColorConstants::Svg'
.\sipQtGuiQColorConstantsSvg.cpp(372): error C2065: 'darkorange': undeclared identifier
.\sipQtGuiQColorConstantsSvg.cpp(383): error C2039: 'darkorchid': is not a member of 'QColorConstants::Svg'
C:\Qt\Qt5.15.0\5.15.0\msvc2015_64\include\QtGui\qcolor.h(338): note: see declaration of 'QColorConstants::Svg'
.\sipQtGuiQColorConstantsSvg.cpp(383): error C2065: 'darkorchid': undeclared identifier
.\sipQtGuiQColorConstantsSvg.cpp(394): error C2039: 'darkred': is not a member of 'QColorConstants::Svg'
C:\Qt\Qt5.15.0\5.15.0\msvc2015_64\include\QtGui\qcolor.h(338): note: see declaration of 'QColorConstants::Svg'
.\sipQtGuiQColorConstantsSvg.cpp(394): error C2065: 'darkred': undeclared identifier
.\sipQtGuiQColorConstantsSvg.cpp(405): error C2039: 'darksalmon': is not a member of 'QColorConstants::Svg'
C:\Qt\Qt5.15.0\5.15.0\msvc2015_64\include\QtGui\qcolor.h(338): note: see declaration of 'QColorConstants::Svg'
.\sipQtGuiQColorConstantsSvg.cpp(405): error C2065: 'darksalmon': undeclared identifier
.\sipQtGuiQColorConstantsSvg.cpp(416): error C2039: 'darkseagreen': is not a member of 'QColorConstants::Svg'
C:\Qt\Qt5.15.0\5.15.0\msvc2015_64\include\QtGui\qcolor.h(338): note: see declaration of 'QColorConstants::Svg'
.\sipQtGuiQColorConstantsSvg.cpp(416): error C2065: 'darkseagreen': undeclared identifier
.\sipQtGuiQColorConstantsSvg.cpp(427): error C2039: 'darkslateblue': is not a member of 'QColorConstants::Svg'
C:\Qt\Qt5.15.0\5.15.0\msvc2015_64\include\QtGui\qcolor.h(338): note: see declaration of 'QColorConstants::Svg'
.\sipQtGuiQColorConstantsSvg.cpp(427): error C2065: 'darkslateblue': undeclared identifier
.\sipQtGuiQColorConstantsSvg.cpp(438): error C2039: 'darkslategray': is not a member of 'QColorConstants::Svg'
C:\Qt\Qt5.15.0\5.15.0\msvc2015_64\include\QtGui\qcolor.h(338): note: see declaration of 'QColorConstants::Svg'
.\sipQtGuiQColorConstantsSvg.cpp(438): error C2065: 'darkslategray': undeclared identifier
.\sipQtGuiQColorConstantsSvg.cpp(449): error C2039: 'darkslategrey': is not a member of 'QColorConstants::Svg'
C:\Qt\Qt5.15.0\5.15.0\msvc2015_64\include\QtGui\qcolor.h(338): note: see declaration of 'QColorConstants::Svg'
.\sipQtGuiQColorConstantsSvg.cpp(449): error C2065: 'darkslategrey': undeclared identifier
.\sipQtGuiQColorConstantsSvg.cpp(460): error C2039: 'darkturquoise': is not a member of 'QColorConstants::Svg'
C:\Qt\Qt5.15.0\5.15.0\msvc2015_64\include\QtGui\qcolor.h(338): note: see declaration of 'QColorConstants::Svg'
.\sipQtGuiQColorConstantsSvg.cpp(460): error C2065: 'darkturquoise': undeclared identifier
.\sipQtGuiQColorConstantsSvg.cpp(471): error C2039: 'darkviolet': is not a member of 'QColorConstants::Svg'
C:\Qt\Qt5.15.0\5.15.0\msvc2015_64\include\QtGui\qcolor.h(338): note: see declaration of 'QColorConstants::Svg'
.\sipQtGuiQColorConstantsSvg.cpp(471): error C2065: 'darkviolet': undeclared identifier
.\sipQtGuiQColorConstantsSvg.cpp(482): error C2039: 'deeppink': is not a member of 'QColorConstants::Svg'
C:\Qt\Qt5.15.0\5.15.0\msvc2015_64\include\QtGui\qcolor.h(338): note: see declaration of 'QColorConstants::Svg'
.\sipQtGuiQColorConstantsSvg.cpp(482): error C2065: 'deeppink': undeclared identifier
.\sipQtGuiQColorConstantsSvg.cpp(493): error C2039: 'deepskyblue': is not a member of 'QColorConstants::Svg'
C:\Qt\Qt5.15.0\5.15.0\msvc2015_64\include\QtGui\qcolor.h(338): note: see declaration of 'QColorConstants::Svg'
.\sipQtGuiQColorConstantsSvg.cpp(493): error C2065: 'deepskyblue': undeclared identifier
.\sipQtGuiQColorConstantsSvg.cpp(504): error C2039: 'dimgray': is not a member of 'QColorConstants::Svg'
C:\Qt\Qt5.15.0\5.15.0\msvc2015_64\include\QtGui\qcolor.h(338): note: see declaration of 'QColorConstants::Svg'
.\sipQtGuiQColorConstantsSvg.cpp(504): error C2065: 'dimgray': undeclared identifier
.\sipQtGuiQColorConstantsSvg.cpp(515): error C2039: 'dimgrey': is not a member of 'QColorConstants::Svg'
C:\Qt\Qt5.15.0\5.15.0\msvc2015_64\include\QtGui\qcolor.h(338): note: see declaration of 'QColorConstants::Svg'
.\sipQtGuiQColorConstantsSvg.cpp(515): error C2065: 'dimgrey': undeclared identifier
.\sipQtGuiQColorConstantsSvg.cpp(526): error C2039: 'dodgerblue': is not a member of 'QColorConstants::Svg'
C:\Qt\Qt5.15.0\5.15.0\msvc2015_64\include\QtGui\qcolor.h(338): note: see declaration of 'QColorConstants::Svg'
.\sipQtGuiQColorConstantsSvg.cpp(526): error C2065: 'dodgerblue': undeclared identifier
.\sipQtGuiQColorConstantsSvg.cpp(537): error C2039: 'firebrick': is not a member of 'QColorConstants::Svg'
C:\Qt\Qt5.15.0\5.15.0\msvc2015_64\include\QtGui\qcolor.h(338): note: see declaration of 'QColorConstants::Svg'
.\sipQtGuiQColorConstantsSvg.cpp(537): error C2065: 'firebrick': undeclared identifier
.\sipQtGuiQColorConstantsSvg.cpp(548): error C2039: 'floralwhite': is not a member of 'QColorConstants::Svg'
C:\Qt\Qt5.15.0\5.15.0\msvc2015_64\include\QtGui\qcolor.h(338): note: see declaration of 'QColorConstants::Svg'
.\sipQtGuiQColorConstantsSvg.cpp(548): error C2065: 'floralwhite': undeclared identifier
.\sipQtGuiQColorConstantsSvg.cpp(559): error C2039: 'forestgreen': is not a member of 'QColorConstants::Svg'
C:\Qt\Qt5.15.0\5.15.0\msvc2015_64\include\QtGui\qcolor.h(338): note: see declaration of 'QColorConstants::Svg'
.\sipQtGuiQColorConstantsSvg.cpp(559): error C2065: 'forestgreen': undeclared identifier
.\sipQtGuiQColorConstantsSvg.cpp(570): error C2039: 'fuchsia': is not a member of 'QColorConstants::Svg'
C:\Qt\Qt5.15.0\5.15.0\msvc2015_64\include\QtGui\qcolor.h(338): note: see declaration of 'QColorConstants::Svg'
.\sipQtGuiQColorConstantsSvg.cpp(570): error C2065: 'fuchsia': undeclared identifier
.\sipQtGuiQColorConstantsSvg.cpp(581): error C2039: 'gainsboro': is not a member of 'QColorConstants::Svg'
C:\Qt\Qt5.15.0\5.15.0\msvc2015_64\include\QtGui\qcolor.h(338): note: see declaration of 'QColorConstants::Svg'
.\sipQtGuiQColorConstantsSvg.cpp(581): error C2065: 'gainsboro': undeclared identifier
.\sipQtGuiQColorConstantsSvg.cpp(592): error C2039: 'ghostwhite': is not a member of 'QColorConstants::Svg'
C:\Qt\Qt5.15.0\5.15.0\msvc2015_64\include\QtGui\qcolor.h(338): note: see declaration of 'QColorConstants::Svg'
.\sipQtGuiQColorConstantsSvg.cpp(592): fatal error C1003: error count exceeds 100; stopping compilation
Generating Code...
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\amd64\cl.EXE"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\bin\amd64\nmake.exe"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: 'cd' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
```

Comment: I would recommend installing PyQt via a command like "pip install PyQt5" and using an IDE like PyCharm.

Comment: Using python 2.7.14 and I Get the following error:

Collecting pyqt5
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyqt5 (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for pyqt5